# Remove a child from firebase without knowing the key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: database]

I need to remove the unknown id child, but I know only the value. I've tried reading all values and inserting back all except that one. Is there any easy way to do this.

sample data:
{ unknownKey : knownValue , ...}

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add your code.

Comment: if you have the value then loop your array then if you find the same value that you have, get the key of it and use that key to remove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take in the `wishlist` object and loop through each key, value pair and find the value that matches, using the key. Then you can just remove it using the key you found.

```
//---use firebase code to get the wishlistObj---, for now I'll use another value
var wishlistObj = {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"};
var keysArray = Object.keys(wishlistObj);

for (var i = 0; i < keysArray.length; i++) {
    var key = keysArray[i];
    var value = wishlistObj[key];
    if (value === "value3") {
        //You know that the "key" variable is the value of the key of that value you know
        //Now you can use that key to take the value out of the firebase database
    
        //Try
        objectReference.child(key).removeValue() //Where the objectReference variable is the reference to the wishlist object in your database 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, It helped a lot. But still removeValue() doesn;t work so I changed it to only remove() and its working fine

Comment: Yeah i know my firebase code wasn't right, i think i got that from Java 

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what you are doing at the moment, you must also handle the case where the value you are searching for exists multiple times in the wishlist. Rather than loop through the data and call `remove()` on each match, which may make one or more database writes, you can instead use an [`update()` operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields) to handle one or more deletions at the same time **as a single database write**.

As an example, this first code block, which may make one or more database writes, can be flattened into a single database write.

```
for (const [key, value] in Object.values(wishlistObj)) {
    if (value === valueToRemove) {
        wishlistRef.child(key).remove()
            .then(...)
            .catch(...);
    }
}
```

can be replaced by

```
changesObject = {};
for (const [key, value] in Object.values(wishlistObj)) {
    if (value === valueToRemove) {
        // setting the value as "null" will delete data at
        // this location when written to the database
        changesObject[key] = null; 
    }
}
// commit the changes
wishlistRef.update(changesObject)
     .then(/* ... */)
     .catch(/* ... */);
```

Rather than download and loop through the entire object searching for the `known id` value, it is more efficient to make use of a [sorting by value query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sort_data) and only download the keys that contain the value `known id`. For small datasets, the performance difference is minor, but for large datasets this can save bandwidth as well as time.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/database';

const valueToRemove = 'known id';

const wishlistRef = firebase.database.ref('/path/to/wishlist');

wishlistRef.orderByValue().equalTo(valueToRemove).once('value')
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    if (!querySnapshot.hasChildren()) {
      return; // value not found. do nothing
    }
    
    const changesObject = {};
    
    querySnapshot.forEach((matchSnapshot) => {
      // here matchSnapshot.val() == valueToRemove, so mark it's key for deletion.
      changesObject[matchSnapshot.key] = null;
    });
    
    // commit any changes
    return wishlistRef.update(changesObject);
  })
  .then(() => {
    // if here, value was deleted successfully
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // todo: handle any errors
  });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It means a lot❤